# Do we need (derivation) tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I have noticed that there exists [derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivation) tag.

It contains two questions at the moment, so it might be quite recent. Maybe it was created [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/752070/revisions).

The [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/derivation/info) is empty, but it seems that the tag is intended for questions about derivation of some fact, steps in some derivation, etc. (Judging from the questions that have been tagged with this tag so far.)

Will such tag be useful? Do we need it?

It smells of a [meta-tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags) a little.

Comment: I assumed this was tag for functions satisfying the Leibniz rule!

Comment: And I agree that it is a meta-tag given those examples and that we probably don't need it.

Comment: It seems that the tag has already been removed from both questions where it was used: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/758775/revisions), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/752070/revisions).

Comment: A newer discussion about the same tag: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16943/derivation-tag-removed